# TypeScript + React: How do I type a `rest` props that collects the rest of the props into an object and later spread them to some element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```js
function Foo({
  children,
  ...rest
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  /*rest: how do I type `rest`? */
}) {
  return (
    <span style={{ background: "red" }} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </span>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Foo style={{ background: "blue" }}>Hello CodeSandbox</Foo>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-type-rest-huv2z?file=/src/App.tsx:50-412

`Foo` is used to override the props that `span` accepts. How do I type `rest` in `Foo`?

Answer (score 9):

You can't type the spread portion of the object directly, but you can add the necessary properties with the union type (`&`).

In this case, the extra properties you want to allow are of type `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>`. So you end up with:

```
function Foo({
  children,
  ...rest
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
} & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>) {
  return (
    <span style={{ background: "red" }} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </span>
  );
}
```

As an aside, you can avoid manually typing the `children` property using the `React.FunctionComponent` type. This actually avoids the union definition and is a bit more idiomatic in React code.

```
const Foo: React.FunctionComponent<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>> = ({
  children,
  ...rest
}) => {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I heard `React.FunctionComponent` is not recommended anymore?

Comment: I tried to this on `img` element but it seems like the autocomplete is not working correctly https://codesandbox.io/s/type-images-66y2s?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: You've used a type that doesn't match: you can see the type for the `img` tag by hovering over it. You can use `JSX.IntrinsicElements["img"]` in this case (this also works for `span` so may be a more generic solution if you need one.

Comment: You don't have to manually type the `children` in the first case either, since it's already a part of a native `<span>`

Comment: You can give your component props the type `PropsWithChildren<T>` (imported from `react`) - where T is your props Type, that way you don't have to define your children type in your props type

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `[x:string]: any;` like

```
function Foo({
  children,
  ...rest
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  [rest:string]: any;
}) {
  return (
    <span style={{ background: "red" }} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </span>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Foo style={{ background: "blue" }} id="example">Hello CodeSandbox</Foo>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes but it is not type safe. For type safety, prefer the `& React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>` solution from the other answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this as a type:

```
{
  children: React.ReactNode;
  /*rest: how do I type `rest`? */
} & HTMLProps<HTMLSpanElement>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).